# Removing Neovim window focus

Tags: themes, neovim

I love the Gruvbox theme. The only problem I've ever had with it was when it started to cause a `W18` warning on all of my newly opened buffers so, I finally decided to get rid of it. I've replaced it with the Tokyonight theme, but I've come across another issue: it doesn't seem to override the settings for `transparency` nor `dim-inactive` like the example config says it would. Frustrated and incompetent, I'm asking you guys at SO as a last resort if there is a way to remove the inactive pane/buffer dim using the solely the Neovim API in Lua?

- Updating the Tokyonight config to the following
  [image]

  - The above configuration resulted in this which is anything but what it's supposed to do.
    [image]
- This is what I expect to happen (with the statusbar visibility toggling on focus and other default behaviors)
  [image]

Comment: Open an issue in the tokyo-night repo? I am sure this is a config problem.

Comment: . As movies like Skyscraper say "try turning it off and on again", I did -- on a larger scale -- and it works!  I erased my macbook and am reinstalling everything all over again. So far, all the issues presented above have been resolved (and a few more) :)